# Groupby a column which is a list of objects but results in error: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python, arrays, error-handling, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame like this. The column "port" is a list of items and I want to `groupby` column "port":

```
df1
Out[107]: 
   model                port
0      1  [a, b, c, d, e, f]
1      2  [e, r, t, u, y, y]
2      3  [d, f, g, h, j, u]
3      4  [a, b, c, d, e, f]
4      5  [e, r, t, u, w, y]
5      6  [b, c, j, k, n, v]
```

Am using this code to group:

```
df1.groupby(['port'])['model'].sum()
```

It gives an error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Anything wrong? I've searched this error but couldn't find anything applicable to this situation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to convert the `port` column into a hashable type. For example, you could use `tuple` instead of `np.ndarray`. Something like this:

```py
df1.port = df1.port.map(tuple)
```

If you really need the `port` column to have arrays the rest of the time, you could do this operation without modifying the original array:

```py
df1.assign(port=df.port.map(tuple)).groupby("port").model.sum()
```

Comment: Thank you @Nathan for the prompt answer!

Comment: No problem; welcome to StackOverflow! If it solves the problem for you, you can click the check mark on the left side to "accept" this answer and let others know your question is resolved